# Error starting artifactory ubuntu after uninstall and reinstall

Tags: tomcat, artifactory

```
Jul 03 14:06:53 -Server su[4580]: - ??? root:artifactory
Jul 03 14:06:53 -Server artifactoryManage.sh[4548]: ** ERROR: Artifactory Tomcat server did not start. Please check the logs
```

Comment: Can you add what you're trying to do and what you've tried?

Comment: well, did you check the logs? ;)